# how etc/hosts file is created during Centos 4.9 installation

Tags: linux, centos, hosts

We have our servers running CentOS 4.9. I want to find how `/etc/hosts` file is created during installation.

A related question here ([What creates /etc/hosts (RHEL 5.5)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44962/what-creates-etc-hosts-rhel-5-5)) says that in RHEL 5 `/etc/hosts` file is created by ananconda.

We use `anaconda-10.1.1.46-4.x86_64.rpm`. I extracted this RPM and found a file `/usr/lib/anaconda/network.py`. This Python file creates the `/etc/hosts` file.

After reading through this python script I could see that `localhost.localdomain` domain alias name should be added in the `/etc/hosts` file.

But during installation I could see that the `/etc/hosts` file is created with only.

```
127.0.0.1   loghost
```

We also have an `ks.cfg` file which creates `/etc/hosts` file with the following content

```
127.0.0.1         localhost loghost
```

So after installation and reboot, the `/etc/hosts` file is created as specified in the `ks.cfg` file.

I am bit confused here how the `/etc/hosts` file is created with only `127.0.0.1    loghost` during installation.

## EDIT:

Note:  We bundle our application RPMs with the CentOS rpms and build an ISO.

The real problem is we are moving from CentOS 4.9 to 6.5. In CentOS 6.5 setup-2.8.14-20 rpm creates the hosts file with the following contents

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

`localhost.localdomain` is added in the hosts file.

So we are trying to find the difference between CentOS 4.9 & 6.5 `/etc/hosts` file creation during installation, because our application is tightly bound with the entries in `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the answer to your question as-asked, but I think I have the solution to your real problem.

Instead of simply writing out a fresh `/etc/hosts` file, potentially overwriting the one already present, you can append the entries you need to the end. There is no functional difference between:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost loghost
```

and

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 loghost
```

That is, you do not need to collect all names for 127.0.0.1 on the same line. You just need to append a single line with the `loghost` entry you need *after* Anaconda creates the stock version.

Since you're doing this from an RPM you created, it means that you replace the way you're currently modifying or creating `/etc/hosts` with something like this in your RPM's `%post` script:

```
if ! grep -q loghost /etc/hosts
then
    echo '127.0.0.1 loghost' >> /etc/hosts
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.I have edited my question with more information.

Comment: @Arun: Does my added `%post` script snippet help?

Comment: /etc/hosts file gets created before our RPMs are installed. One of our RPM installation depends on the entries in the /etc/hosts file. We have an check in the %post section of our RPM spec file checking for entries in /etc/hosts file. We see differences between contents of /etc/hosts(before our RPM is installed) file in CentOS 4.9 & CentOS 6.5 before our RPM gets installed. So we are trying to find how /etc/hosts file is created during installation. The %post section in our ks.cfg file overwrite the /etc/hosts file(which gets created during installation) after installing all the RPMs

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Use your %post script to *make* /etc/hosts look the way your RPM needs it to look by appending the entries you need. Don't just blindly overwrite it.